# Почему не используются индексы при запросе?

Tags: sql, firebird, индексы

Есть таблица packets в Firebird 2.1.5:

```
CREATE TABLE PACKETS (
TS        TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
FILTERID  SMALLINT NOT NULL,
PROTO     SMALLINT,
SRC_IP    CHAR(16),
SRC_PORT  INTEGER,
DST_IP    CHAR(16),
DST_PORT  INTEGER,
SENT      INTEGER,
RECV      INTEGER,
ID        INTEGER NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE PACKETS ADD CONSTRAINT PK_PACKETS PRIMARY KEY (ID);
```

Для поля ID при создании первичного ключа был создан индекс PK_PACKETS.
Есть запрос для подсчета количества строк в таблице:

```
select count(id) from packets p
```

а это его план:

```
PLAN (P NATURAL)
```

Как видно, индекс не используется и запрос будет выполняться очень долго.
Если в запрос добавить условие на поле id, то индекс будет использоваться:

```
select count(id) from packets p where p.id>0;
PLAN (P INDEX (PK_PACKETS))
```

Как можно посчитать количество записей в таблице, чтобы использовались индексы? Или это какое-то ограничение СУБД?

Comment: А если так написать:

select count(distinct id) from packets p

будет использоваться индекс?

Comment: нет: `select count(distinct id) from packets p ` `PLAN (P NATURAL)`

Comment: Приблизительное колчество записей в таблице можно узнать так:                         `select 1/r.rdb$statistics from rdb$indices r
where r.rdb$index_name = 'PK_PACKETS';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это ограничение СУБД. Оно связано с многоверсионной архитектурой. При подсчёте движок проверяет доступность строки для текущей транзакции, поэтому нужно просмотреть каждую строку.

Такое было и в PostgreSQL, пока в какой-то из 9 версий не сделали `visibility map`

Comment: Похоже дело действительно в этом. Вот такое описание нашлось для Firebird:"COUNT (*) является очень дороrой операцией, потому что она может работать только пройдя по всему набору данных и точно подсчитав каждую строку, которая видима как подтвержденная для текущей транзакции. Это число должно трактоваться как "rрубый счетчик", потому что может оказаться неверным, если друrая транзакция подтверждает работу."  (Хелен Борри, Руководство разработчика баз данных, с.403)

Comment: Это также объясняет еще один момент: количество чтений из таблицы остается одинаковым для случая когда индекс используется и когда не используется. Просто в первом случае это будут не индексированные чтения, а во втором - индексированные. Т.е. в любом случае таблица читается целиком.

Answer (score 0):

Индекс и нужен только при поиске по условию. А если нужно выбрать все записи таблицы (как в первом запросе), то есть индекс или нет - безразлично. Поэтому и Natural.

Comment: Нужно только _посчитать_ количество записей в таблице, выбирать их не нужно. Почему-то я считал, что пройтись по индексу всегда выгодней серверу  чем читать всю таблицу.

Comment: нужно и прочитать индекс и сбегать в таблицу проверить версию записи (вдруг параллельная транзакция инсертнула что-то и не закомитила - это считать не надо, а в индексе инфы об этом нет).